# how to use q.all in Angular Js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-services

i am using angular q.all function. this is not working properly

```
  var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  var a=1,b=2;
  myService.doBoth(a,b).then(function(a){
     $scope.blah =a;
  });
});

app.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
      doBoth: function(a,b){

       $q.all([
        (function() {

            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.get('foo.json').then(function(data){
                d.resolve(data);
            });
            return d.promise;
        })(),
        (function() {
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.get('bar.json').then(function(data){
                d.resolve(data);
            });
            return d.promise;
        })()
    ]).then(function(responses) {
        console.log(responses); //array of your responses
    });
      }
    }
})
```

i have this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at new  (app.js:5)

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get()` as it is returns a promise. The need for creating a deferred promise is redundant. You also need to return the promise returned by `$q.all()`, to make it work with your controller.

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  var a=1,b=2;
  myService.doBoth(a,b).then(function(response){
     var foo = response[0]; // foo result
     var bar = response[1]; // bar result
  });
});

app.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
      doBoth: function(a,b){
       return $q.all([
            $http.get('foo.json'),
            $http.get('bar.json')
       ]);
      }
    };
});
```